# Low-Power library question

Tags: sleep

i'm study the Low-Power library to better undertand how it works.
In [this](https://goo.gl/tdofMP) part of code i have some question.

Sometime he uses commands like:

```
power_timer1_disable();
power_timer0_disable();
```

but in other part of code, example "TIMER2_OFF":

```
if (TCCR2B & CS22) clockSource |= (1 << CS22);
if (TCCR2B & CS21) clockSource |= (1 << CS21);
if (TCCR2B & CS20) clockSource |= (1 << CS20);

// Remove the clock source to shutdown Timer2
TCCR2B &= ~(1 << CS22);
TCCR2B &= ~(1 << CS21);
TCCR2B &= ~(1 << CS20);

power_timer2_disable();
```

he uses the register code and, in the end, the function.

Someone can explain to me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing basically this:

```
clockSource = TCCR2B & (_BV(CS22) | _BV(CS21) | _BV(CS20)); // store prescaler
TCCR2B &= ~(_BV(CS22) | _BV(CS21) | _BV(CS20));             // select "no source" - disable clock source
power_timer2_disable(); // disable whole timer2 in Power Reduction Register
```

Definition of power_timer2_disable macro is:

```
#define power_timer2_disable()  (PRR |= (uint8_t)(1 << PRTIM2))
```

In short, you have to turn off the clock source before the power gets cut off by PRR register (to avoid unexpected behaviour).

> **Power Reduction Register**
>
> The Power Reduction Register (PRR), provides a method to stop the
> clock to individual peripherals to reduce power consumption. The
> current state of the peripheral is frozen and the I/O registers can
> not be read or written. ***Resources used by the peripheral when stopping
> the clock will remain occupied, hence the peripheral should in most
> cases be disabled before stopping the clock.*** Waking up a module, which
> is done by clearing the bit in PRR, puts the module in the same state
> as before shutdown. Module shutdown can be used in Idle mode and
> Active mode to significantly reduce the overall power consumption. In
> all other sleep modes, the clock is already stopped.

Comment: Thx KIIV!
Is it in the datasheet those advice before use the, for example, power_timer2_disable?

Comment: @MarkCalaway It's definitely mentioned for the ADC module. I didn't checked it for the Timers.